# Which token to use for keywords field in metatag module for a node

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

I want to take the value from metatag keywords field of a node and use it in a sitemap.

I have tried the below token values but nothing has worked for me. Please advice

```
[node:source:metatag:keywords],
[metatag:keywords],
[node:metatag:keywords],
[node:metatag:news_keywords],

[node:taxonomy-forums:metatag:keywords],
[node:original:metatag:keywords],
[node:field-category:metatag:keywords],
[node:field_search_keyword]
```

Comment: it seems drupal core had a bug I had to upgrade to drupal 7.31

Answer (score 0):

summery about my solution to the same problem - get keywords token -
if another one face it like me 2 hours ago - not drupal bug -

first get all tokens

- use devel module or
- manually

**Get tokens manually**

```
print theme('token_tree', array('node'), TRUE, TRUE);
```

then token_replace

```
print token_replace('[node:metatag:keywords]', array('node' => $node));
```